# How to show grid in mid of screen with with vertical slide option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have seen that some applications have grid view or form visible on alert box with vertical slide but really do not have any idea of how to achieve this.

Upto my knowledge i think this is possible with jquery..

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jquery ui-dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

An example of login form inside a modal will look like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            SUBMIT: function() {
                $('#loginForm').submit();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6FGqN/676/)

Comment: Thanks sir for ur response .if i have to send parameters on submit button click to another server side page then how to do that??plz help me ...

Comment: I don't know which language you are using for processing the form. In the form `action` write the `url` of the script and get the values using `input` name

Comment: Read [Working with HTML Forms in ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/working-with-pages/4-working-with-forms)

Comment: Sir does this mean that there is no need to send values as url parameters as we used to do in ajax submit button click ..

Comment: Form has attribute named as `method` if `method` is set as `POST` the values will not be visible in the `url` and if the method is `GET` the values will be visible in the `url`